# How do I prevent the facebook login page from taking over my home page app?

Tags: ipad, web, facebook-social-plugins

I have a iPad home page app that I'm trying to integrate a facebook like button. Everything works fine if the user is already logged in, but if the user is not logged in the facebook login page takes over my app page and after login does not return to my app. Is there a way to make facebook login using an iframe?

My app is a web app not a native IOS app. It is setup with a manifest file and the user adds it to their home page. Because the app can have different URLs and all we want to do is provide like functionality, registering the app is not available to me.

What I want to know is there a way for facebook to **open the login page in an iframe** like the like dialog when the user clicks the like button? Right now I'm using the social plugin for the like button, but if the user isn't logged in to facebook the login page replaces my web app. Is there a way to make the login page use an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it in a `<div>` worked for me